# How can I create an IEnumerable from Entity Framework async?

Tags: blazor, devexpress, blazor-server-side, devexpress-blazor

I have an extension method that creates an expression to return a set of rows in the database:

```
public static class SkillsExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Skill> AllSkills(this LouisHoweDbContext context)
    {
        return context.Skills.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
    }
}
```

The code above does not touch the database (yet) and therefore it is not declared async - correct?

I now use this is a Blazor (server side .NET 7) app. I am using DevExpress controls.

```
<DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Your skills:" Field="@nameof(RegisterPageModel.Skills)" ColSpanMd="6">
    <DxTagBox Data="@NoTrackingDbContext.AllSkills()"
              TextFieldName="@nameof(Skill.Name)"
              @bind-Values="@RegisterPageModel.Skills"/>
</DxFormLayoutItem>
```

The above is the Blazor page and therefore I believe it is able to properly handle async methods. But I have no control over this as I pass the method to the DevExpress component.

Is there a way I can force this to be async? And if so, should I? Or is this a case where there is no advantage to async calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use async to get the values, `Data` expects an IEnumerable

```
 <DxTagBox Data="@allSkills" ... />

  private IEnumerable<Skill> allSkills = default!;
  overide OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    allSkills = await NoTrackingDbContext.AllSkills();
  }
```

and

```
    public static Task<IEnumerable<Skill>> AllSkills(this LouisHoweDbContext context)
    {
        return context.Skills.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Although i doubt the use of an extension method here, make it a member of an injectable service (repository).

Comment: Thank you and a follow-up question. Why is there no ToEnumerableAsync() call? As to your suggestion about making this injectable, I posted a question and hope to get your reasoning - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76025233/what-are-the-trade-offs-of-injecting-a-dbcontext-to-call-queries-and-injecting-e thanks

Comment: Also, I think the correct code is:  
`  public static async Task<List<Skill>> AllSkills(this LouisHoweDbContext context)
  {
   return await context.Skills.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToListAsync();
  }`

Comment: In a method like this you can "elide async and await", a small saving.

Comment: I'm of the school of being explicit. And granted, that's a stylistic decision that we each do what works best for us. I use () in my boolean expressions so there's no need to remember precedence, I keep the {} for a namespace, and I still declare main(). I figure clarity never hurts. And in the case of the above, it actually can make a difference - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html Again, thanks for the solution.