# What are the trade-offs of injecting a DbContext to call queries and injecting each query method?

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

I presently inject the DbContexts (have a tracking and no tracking context) and when I need to run a query, I call an extension method as follows:

Extension:

```
public static class SkillsExtensions
{
    public static async Task<List<Skill>> AllSkills(this LouisHoweDbContext context)
    {
        return await context.Skills.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

page.razor.cs:

```
[Inject]
private NoTrackingDbContext NoTrackingDbContext { get; set; } = null!;

private List<Skill>? _allSkills;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _allSkills = await NoTrackingDbContext.AllSkills();
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Instead I could have a service where that service had the various query methods. The two ways I see to do that are:

1. Methods I add to the base DbContext class my two DbContext classes inherit from.
2. A class that is passed the DbContext as part of the query.

Key to this is that every query can be called by either DbContext class. While a number of the queries will only be called by one of them, most of the queries will be called by both, the appropriate one at the appropriate time.

I'm not asking for an opinion here but rather the specific trade-offs of each approach.

**Update:**

I am adding the DbContext classes as services:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<TrackingDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LouisHoweDb"))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<NoTrackingDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LouisHoweDb"))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
```

Comment: How are you generating your DbContexts?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I just added an update to answer your question. Short answer, I'm calling AddDbContextFactory(). thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is somewhat novel: You're not a clean design advocate.  You're injecting an intrastructure/Data domain object - the `DbContext`  - directly into the UI domain.

While you're adding a `DbContextFactory` you don't appear to be using it to generate *unit of work* contexts.  The Microsoft recommended practice is documented her: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor.

The primary reason for adopting this approach is that Blazor is inherently async.  At some point [soon] you will attempt to use the same context in two async code blocks and **Bang!**

The advantages of using a service are separation of code into domains, and using the `DbContextFactory` in your service to implement *Unit of Work* DbContexts for each transaction.  You can turn on/off tracking on each context based on the type of action.

A observation: Why do you switch between a tracked and untracked context?  A transaction is either:

1. A query [no mutation and therefore no tracking required]
2. A command [mutation anf therefore tracking required]